# Bypass SonicWall FireWall

Tags: firewall

My work place uses a dell sonic wall firewall and it is set to record all the websites i have visited and how much times i visit these websites and i don't want my boss to see that i have been playing games on MocoSpace. I am currently using a VPN but i am not sure if that will bypass the firewall. How can i bypass this and stop the firewall from recording the websites i visit? Need help please.

Comment: A VPN only encrypts the traffic.  They can still see everything you are doing.  How about doing some work instead?

Comment: @Keltari. doesn't a VPN send all traffic in an encrypted tunnel, so the only traffic that would be visible, would between the client and the VPN server.  I don't disagree though a VPN doesn't stop the firewall from issuing a MiTM certificate, and having the ability, to decrypt the traffic between the VPN and the client.

Comment: @Ramhound unless dns is changed to the VPN, then they can see all the DNS requests.  And that is only the network side.  naturally they can see what is going on, on the computer itself, regardless of the VPN.

Comment: @Keltari - That isn't how how a VPN works.  Its a encrypted tunnel between you and the VPN.

Comment: @Ramhound that is how a vpn works. unless you use an encrypted DNS service, the DNS lookups still go through the local DNS provider

Comment: I'm late to the party here, but you're both right. It totally depends on how the VPN is configured. If you're using a VPN from a business, the IT staff can configure it to "tunnel all" or only tunnel certain connections, it depends on if some routes or all routes are tunneled. If it's "tunnel all" then no, DNS traffic will not go out the interface, it will traverse the VPN. If it's not tunnel all, then it will hit the DNS. For public VPNs you pay a monthly fee to, most of them tunnel everything through the VPN.

Answer (score 0):

Remote desktop offsite and wait for them to ask you about all the traffic. Then tell the truth and receive your pink slip.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways to bypass the firewall. So We will use sonic firewalls which are best and also resolve your issues.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).